# add bottom bar with function type onclicklistener

Tags: android, onclicklistener

i have create a xml for a bottom bar.
Implements this bottom bar in other activity xml with this line of code:

```
<include layout="@layout/bottom_bar" />
```

where bottom_bar are the name of the file xml of the bottom bar.

I created a MainActivity and when i launch the app i see the MainActivity content with the bottom bar.

how to set an onclicklistener in one button of the bottom bar and make it work in every activity of my app?

this is the bottom_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dip"
        android:background="#ff44ff">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dip"
        android:layout_width="75dip"
        android:layout_height="75dip"
        android:background ="@drawable/icona" />

</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

this the MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflator = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LinearLayout insertPoint = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_content);
        List views = new ArrayList();
        //create a dynamic view
        Iterator<Notizia> it = (Dati.listaNotizie).iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()){
            final Notizia not = it.next();

            View view = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.layout_notizie, null);
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.notizieTitolo);
            int pixel = (int) (10 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
            TextView textView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.notizieSottoTitolo);
            textView.setText(not.getTitolo());
            textView1.setText(not.getSottoTitolo());

            textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                Dati.setNewsListaAttuale("http://www.rhinos.it/rhinos-news/");
                SingleNewsActivity.setNotizia(not);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SingleNewsActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);   
                startActivity(intent);
              }
            });
            view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            views.add(view);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<views.size(); i++)
            insertPoint.addView((View) views.get(i));
    }
}
```

I can create a java class or a function for the bottom bar and implement this class/function in the MainActivity.java ?

Comment: You can access its view from your activity only. Please show some more code of your bottom_bar layout file and your activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set id

```
<include android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
layout="@layout/bottom_bar" />
```

then

```
View bottom_bar_container = findViewById(R.id.bottom_bar); 

bottom_bar_container.findViewById(R.id.<your id name which is use inside bottom bar>);
```

Set click listener

Comment: perfect!
it's easy. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set an id in the XML reference of the layout.

```
<include android:id="@+id/yourBottomBarId" layout="@layout/bottom_bar" />
```

Then get it in the activity class by Referencing it.

> ```
> YourBottomBar bottomBar = (YourBottomBar) findViewById(R.id.yourBottomBarId);
> ```

Then get reference to the button contained in your bottomBar view.

```
// Unsure how you want to reference, this is one suggestion.
Button yourButton = bottomBar.getButton();
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Your onClick implementation here.
    }
});
```